# jsonParsed to data.frame

Tags: r, json

I am starting to learn about APIs and JSON files and I faced my first problem:

I imported some information like this:

```
page_data <- GET("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/paises/CA/indicadores/77827")
```

And got an object "application/json". From this object, I applied this:

```
jsonParsed <- content(page_data, "parsed")
```

The problem is: I don't know how to get the information from the serie. I want to know how to convert this format of data into a data.fame object, that I can see both the year and the correspondent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are expecting because I know nothing of this data, but this at least provides a data frame:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- fromJSON("https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/paises/CA/indicadores/77827")

mydata |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  select(series) |> 
  unnest(series) |> 
  unnest(serie) |>
  pivot_longer(-1) |> 
  drop_na(value)

# A tibble: 21 x 3
   pais$id $nome  name  value  
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
 1 CA      Canadá 2000  742288 
 2 CA      Canadá 2001  736398 
 3 CA      Canadá 2002  757942 
 4 CA      Canadá 2003  892412 
 5 CA      Canadá 2004  1023181
 6 CA      Canadá 2005  1169393
 7 CA      Canadá 2006  1315458
 8 CA      Canadá 2007  1464978
 9 CA      Canadá 2008  1549073
10 CA      Canadá 2009  1371152
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The data is about some economic information of Canada. It's just an example to me to start to learn about web scrapping and API's.